Issue with publishing python function as ontology function
Now that palantir workshop supports using python repository as well along with typescript repository, I'm trying to create a python function which makes some api call and return a string value. The code works as expected in the live preview, but when I try to deploy to the ontology function and run it, it starts throwing error.
@function
def getProjectRID_Created_for_palantir_response(projectName: String) -> String:
    url = "https://domainName/compass/api/search/projects"
    headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer XSSSS'
    }
    payload1 = {"pageSize":400,"query":"",}
   
    response1 = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload1)

    if response1.status_code == 200:
        projects = response1.json()["values"]
        projects = json.dumps(projects)
        projects = json.loads(projects)

        for project in projects:
            if project['resource']['name'].lower() == projectName.lower():
                return project['resource']['rid']

        return "project not found"
    else:
        return f"failed to retrive projects:{response1.status_code}"

below is the error what I get
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='domainName', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /compass/api/search/projects (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fdff4543410>: Failed to resolve 'domainName' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")).
Error Parameters: {}
raise NameResolutionError(self.host, self, e) from e
urllib3.exceptions.NameResolutionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fdff4543410>: Failed to resolve 'domainName' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)

I believe we have to create an egress policy and use it in the function, can anyone help me on how to use the egress policy tag here.
I've also created the egress policy and imported to the repository but now sure how to use it in the function

I think the error is pretty much telling you what the problem is. domainName is not a registered domain, it cannot look it up.

how do I fix it?
and how does the live preview work if the domain is not registered?

You fix it by using an actual domain like https://example.com/ instead of https://domainName/ in the url variable.

I did give the actual domain name in the code which I'm working. :)
here i've referenced it as domanName

you are using a legacy api call, can you share the link of document, for egress policy you need to your internal admin team
